# Data processing Data

Tags: data

Is there anything in the world that data, processes the data? I meant that instead of full utilization of CPU, is there any data or program that handles data/logic processing?

Comment: This isn't clear to me what you mean.

Comment: CPU has ALU and is there any virtual CPUs that handle data?

Comment: You mean like http://setiathome.ssl.berkeley.edu/?

Comment: @ CuriousOne. Nope I want to know is there any device/program that can replace CPUs. I know this is silly but I can expect these type of things in this TECH World

Comment: Even virtual CPUs have to run through the physical CPU to do any work.

Comment: You mean like a virtual machine?

Comment: Do you mean something like virtualization? or virtual memory? All of these technologies still rely on an actual physical device, you can't just process data out of thin air.

Comment: One can do analog computation using electronics and other types of physical systems and now quantum computing is emerging as a new paradigm. What's not clear is if one can make any of these techniques perform as well as digital electronics on universal problems. Personally I am skeptical about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I interpreted your question right. Technically, your CPU can be simplified a lot. You can implement a [cellular automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton) in hardware. The one dimensional automaton known as [rule 110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is Turing universal, that is, capable of performing any computation. The rules are pretty simple, as you can see in the link:The automata has only 8 rules and the input tape only two symbols. Given an input string and a clock, at each tic of the clock the automaton  modifies the string based only on one of the eight local nearest-neighbor rules. All the complexity of the CPU was moved into the input tape, where "program and data" become undifferentiated.